# How to rename a mongodb response key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this code:

```
// get a specific question
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Question.findById(req.params.id, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).send();
        }
        console.log(response);
        res.send(response);
    });
});
```

the response is:

```
{ 
    _id: '5b9cee54a05caf7c847aee79',
    title: 'How to make a burger?',
    description:'I wanna know the steps that i need to follow...?',
    answers: 0 
}
```

I want to change the name `_id` in the response to `id` before I sent it to the client, i.e I want the response to be:

```
{ 
    id: '5b9cee54a05caf7c847aee79',
    title: 'How to make a burger?',
    description:'I wanna know the steps that i need to follow...?',
    answers: 0 
}
```

How to accomplish that?

Comment: What is this being sent by? Not the database, but the backend? Also, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is create a new `id` property and then delete the old `_id` property, like this:

```
// get a specific question
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Question.findById(req.params.id, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).send();
        }
        console.log(response);

        // ---
        response.id = response._id;
        delete response._id;
        // ---

        res.send(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope @Kirk Larkin, id property is not added to the response.

Answer (score 0):

You want to rename json Key

IE : `_id` to `id`

There are many ways to do this

**Example 1: String base editing**

```js
var json = [{"_id": "5b9cee54a05caf7c847aee79", "title": "How to make a burger?", "description":"I wanna know the steps that i need to follow...?", "answers": "0" }];

console.log('Old : ' + JSON.stringify(json));
            
json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json).split('"_id":').join('"id":'));

console.log('New : ' + JSON.stringify(json));
```

**Example 2: Object base editing**

```js
var json = '[{"_id": "5b9cee54a05caf7c847aee79", "title": "How to make a burger?", "description":"I wanna know the steps that i need to follow...?", "answers": "0" }]';
            
console.log('OLD : ' + json);
var obj = JSON.parse(json)[0];
obj.id = obj._id;
delete obj._id;

json = JSON.stringify([obj]);

console.log('New : ' + json);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get your JSON, parse it so you can access the properties and simply create the new property `id` on the object and assign it the value of `_id`. Then `delete` `_id` and pass the JSON along (after stringifying it again, depending on how your receiver expects it)?

Some code:

```
const data = JSON.parse(responseJson)
data.id = data._id
delete data._id
const fixedData = JSON.stringify(data)
```

If you have access to the latest features of JS, you can also remove the unwanted `_id` like so:

```
const data = JSON.parse(responseJson)`
fixedData = JSON.stringify({
  ...data,
  id: data._id,
  _id: undefined
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Aggregate** in **MongoDB**

```
db.getCollection('Question').aggregate([{
    $match : {
         "_id" : req.params.id
    }
    },{
    $project : {
        id : '$_id',
        _id : 0, //if not required
        title: 1
        description:1
        answers:1

        }
    } 
    ])
```